# Apple LLVM 5.0 error

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have this error while building new project:

```
fatal error: file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIDevice.h' has been modified since the precompiled header '/Users/ajsthelords/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/1X5NZJEZL1PED/UIKit.pcm' was built
note: after modifying system headers, please delete the module cache at '/Users/ajsthelords/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/1X5NZJEZL1PED'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your module cache is outdated as your SDK has changed since it was last built. To ask Xcode to rebuild it, you have to delete the directory, as indicated in the error message.

```
rm -rf '/Users/ajsthelords/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/1X5NZJEZL1PED'
```

Answer (score 1):

- Remove derived data
- Clean the app & reset simulator
- restart Xcode if necessary